# Inherited RoutePrefixAttribute in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

Currently, my ASP.NET MVC website uses `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` to map routes. I would like to convert this to the new Attribute routing system, but I am missing one small thing there.

The website is multi-language, so every URL needs to be prefixed with a two-letter ISO language code.
In the current implementation, the website uses a custom `RouteHandler` to handle the culture part of all routes. After registering all routes, a loop adds the custom handler and culture constraints to every route.

See below the current implementation:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; 

        // various calls to routes.MapRoute()

        foreach (Route r in routes)
        {
            if (!(r.RouteHandler is SingleCultureMvcRouteHandler))
            {
                r.RouteHandler = new MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler();
                r.Url = "{culture}/" + r.Url;

                // Add the default language
                if (r.Defaults == null)
                    r.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary();
                r.Defaults.Add("culture", Culture.nl.ToString());

                // Add language constraints
                if (r.Constraints == null)
                    r.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
                r.Constraints.Add("culture", new CultureConstraint(Culture.nl.ToString(), Culture.de.ToString(), Culture.en.ToString(), Culture.fr.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Culture enum:**

```
public enum Culture
{
    nl = 1,
    en = 2,
    de = 3,
    fr = 4
}
```

**Custom routehandler:**

```
public class SingleCultureMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler { }

public class MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var culture = requestContext.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString();
        var ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

**Culture constraints**

```
public class CultureConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string[] _values;
    public CultureConstraint(params string[] values)
    {
        this._values = values;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string value = values[parameterName].ToString();
        return _values.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

In order to convert this to the new AttributeRouting, I just thought I'd add a `RoutePrefix` attribute to my base controller, which would handle the culture part. **BUT** it seems inheritance of route attributes is not supported...

The [release notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-mvc-52) of ASP.NET MVC 5.2 state that inherited route attributes are supported in that version by implementing a custom `RouteAttribute` and `DirectRouteProvider`. This is however for the `RouteAttribute`, not for the `RoutePrefixAttribute`.

**What I have tried:**

I've tried to create my own `InheritedRoutePrefixAttribute` by inheriting from the `RoutePrefixAttribute`, but then in order to actually support the inherited route, I still need to create a `InheritedDirectRouteProvider` and override the `GetControllerRouteFactories()` method, which returns a collection of `IDirectRouteFactory`.
So in order to do that, my `InheritedRoutePrefixAttribute` needs to implement the `IDirectRouteFactory` interface, but what to do in the `CreateRoute()` method?

My code so far:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class InheritedRoutePrefixAttribute : RoutePrefixAttribute, IDirectRouteFactory
{
    public RouteEntry CreateRoute(DirectRouteFactoryContext context)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Custom route provider**

```
// Custom direct route provider which supports attribute route inheritance.
public class InheritedDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetControllerRouteFactories(ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        return controllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InheritedRoutePrefixAttribute), inherit: true).Cast<IDirectRouteFactory>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?  I am currently trying to...

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox No, I didn't. I just set the attribute to every controller. It might be supported in ASP.NET Core, but I don't know to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I couldn't either, so I moved on... but would still be interested in the answer if anybody passing by here knows...

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Web Api project and have been playing around with attribute routes (which I think is similar with MVC routes). I wanted to define a global route prefix for my controllers. I created a base class for my controllers which I decorated with the `RoutePrefixAttribute`.

The idea is to define the global route prefix in the base controller class, but also allow controllers that inherit from it to have it's own route prefixes.

For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{
}

[RoutePrefix("values")]
public class ValuesController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{id}")]
    public int Get(int id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The route to call **Get** would then be: `http://{base}:{port}/api/values/{id}`

To do that, I also inherited from DefaultDirectRouteProvider class, but I have overridden **GetRoutePrefix** method instead:

```
public class InheritedRoutePrefixDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override string GetRoutePrefix(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(base.GetRoutePrefix(controllerDescriptor));
        var baseType = controllerDescriptor.ControllerType.BaseType;

        for (var t = baseType; typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(t); t = t.BaseType)
        {
            var a = (t as MemberInfo).GetCustomAttribute<RoutePrefixAttribute>(false);
            if (a != null)
            {
                sb.Insert(0, $"{a.Prefix}{(sb.Length > 0 ? "/": "")}");
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

So what it does is linked the route prefixes together in the controller inheritance chain.